# Joomla Language Pack Issue

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

I am using Language file with my <strike>plugin</strike> component. I have manually placed it in the language folder and named it en-GB.com_componentname.sys.ini and en-GB.com_componentname.ini but whenever my component runs the strings are never translated.

I have tried debugging the language file, at it shows ?? around the strings and publish them as it. COM_COMPONENTNAME_VIEW_TEST , and does not change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a mix-up between plugin and component? Maybe you just confused the terms whilst asking the question.

My first suggestion would be that for a plugin the language file's name would be en-GB.plg_pluginname.sys.ini - for the strings used during install, uninstall and upgrade, and discovery install.

For files used during standard execution of the plugin the filename would be en-GB.plg_pluginname.ini (note that there is no .sys. in this version.

The only other issue is whether you've got the files in the frontend versus the admin application (in the /administrator/ area of your site. Each has its independent /languages/ folder.

If you are talking about a component then the file has com_ in the middle rather than plg_ , and obviously substitute your component/plugin's actual name in place of 'pluginname'.

Comment: I was seeking help for a plugin. Thanks a lot for the help, i did not had an idea about the language folder in the administrator folder. As refereed by you, as soon as i did that, all things started to work. One more question, i also see the files with sys.ini extension in the root languages folder, do i need to place a file there also ?

Answer (score 0):

If want to use a language file just for your plugin, the language file you create should be named after the plugin. The usual convention for plugins, if I'm right is this:

plg_[group]_[plugin_name].ini (for the .sys.ini file the convention is the same)

Besides, if you want to load another language file, you could do something like this:

```
JFactory::getLanguage()->load( 'com_componentname', [ROOT_FOLDER] )
```

Where [ROOT_FOLDER] is usually JPATH_ROOT or JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, depending on where you have your language file ( for plugins, the usual place, at least in recent Joomla versions, is in the administrator.
Besides, make sure the file you created is fully UTF-8 encoded!

I hope it helps!